# Discord Bot Python Message Copy But Changing Content

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want my Discord Python Bot to copy and send a message which I wrote but with an edited content in the message.

For example, if the bot finds in the message a word "test" (as an example a Google link https://www.google.com/search?q=test), then I would like the bot only the edit the "test" in the message and change it to for ex. "nice123" (https://www.google.com/search?q=nice123)

So far, I have this for the message edit -

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    words = ['test']

    for word in words:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.channel.send("nice123")
```

And this for the copy part -

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
```

But I'm kinda struggling with the part of how to implement both of these into one so it copies, edits and sends back.

Comment: You can't have multiple `on_message` events. Have you tried to work with `message.content` in your answer part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment: You can't use multiple `on_message` events, this will stop the bot from working.

There is a simple solution to your question. You can simply `replace` something in your `message.content` with your choice of word(s).

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message): # ONE on_message event
    if message.author == client.user:
        return # Ignore bot messages

    words = ['test']

    for word in words:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.content.replace('test', 'REMOVED')}") # Replace "test" with "REMOVED"

    await client.process_commands(message) # Process commands
```

**The output:**

[image]